# changing CSS elements with javascript for same element id in multiple places

Tags: javascript, css, html

Okay so im pretty new to html/javascript/css through some tutorials and this site it's coming along.  I am attempting to display a button which i use css to overlay with an image when the button is clicked I call a javascript function to send some info to my server as well as replace the button which was clicked with a new button and image overlay. here is the code snippets responsible for this (I'm basically just toggling the visibility on the buttons back and forth):

```
<style type = 'text/css'>
input.btn_follow {
position: absolute;    
right: 2px;
top: 2px;
background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icojam/onebit/48/star-100-icon.png); /* 16px x 16px */
 }

input.btn_unfollow {
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;    
right: 2px;
top: 2px;
background-image: url(http://gologic.com/imagesOld/checkmark%20-%20small.png); 
}

</style>
</head><body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function follow(series, status) {

  var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var request = "follow.php?series="+series+"&status="+status
  xhReq.open("GET", request, false);
  xhReq.send(null);
  var response = xhReq.responseText;
  var IDyes = "follow_"+series
  var IDno =  "unfollow_"+series
 if (response == 1){

  document.getElementById(IDyes).style.visibility='hidden'
  document.getElementById(IDno).style.visibility='visible'
}
else if (response == 0){
  document.getElementById(IDyes).style.visibility='visible'
  document.getElementById(IDno).style.visibility='hidden'
 }
   else if (response == -1){
    alert("you must first login to use the follow request"); // now following show
 } 
}
</script>
```

So all of this kind of works, however for some element ID's they appear multiple times on the same html page. If this is the case only the first instance of the element is the visibility is changed and not for the rest. why is this if they have the same id ? how can I fix this?   here is a link to see this in action on my web page to make this more clear http://ec2-54-234-192-222.compute-1.amazonaws.com/home.php (the button's in  question are the stars)
any help would be greatly appreciated (also if there is a cleaner way scraping what i Have i'd be open to as already starting to resemble spaghetti!) 
thanks -brendan

Comment: No ID should appear more than one time on each page

Comment: why is this? how do I get around displaying multiple instances of same data on a page then?

Comment: Instead of IDs, use classes. They're meant to appear more than once on a page.

Comment: @brendanmorrison To explain... Id's are unique. There is supposed to only be one. This is even evident in your own code.`document.getElementById`. Notice: `getElement` not `getElements` like you find in `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: Okay that make sense ... so if I'm doing similar by class then id everything should work ... Thanks! glad ive been scratching my head with this.. easy fix!

Comment: Classes would be the way to go if you need to change multiple elements at once. Just to note, if you use `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.getElementsByTagName`, you will get an array of elements back, not a single element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as in the comments above Id's should only appear once per page! I'm blaming this on being a newb thanks to @Jeff shaver for clarrifying this